# How to install projet igi 2

Tags: games

How do I install project IGI 2 in ubuntu 12.04? I am new to ubuntu. My laptop model is Lenovo 2049 with 1GB RAM and Celeron processor. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

you can not install Project IGI 2 directly in the Ubuntu 12.04 but you can do it with wine.

- First install wine with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wine
  ```
- Then click .exe file of IGI 2 , then automatically it will launch the game.

I have already checked IGI 2 in wine database.

you must see this link:http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=8121&iTestingId=55231

Important Point : Game works only if compiz is disabled. so you must disable compiz to play IGI.

Answer (score 0):

First, Install 'PlayOnLinux' Applicaton, then create a Virtual Disk for your Windows Program, then you can easily Select the igi2.exe file and then Install and Play it.